# Identifying the best group that are most productive

Tags: data-mining, visualization, data-science-model, data-analysis

can you please give some idea to solve this problem, Below is my data, I want to identify the best inventory based on the CPM(target value) .. For example: I want to be able to say - Business section, on desktop, with Others Ad format for Ireland has better CPM than some other sections, device, ad format.
I tried decision tree, cluster but still not satisfying results!

[image]

Comment: Looks like an unsupervised algorithm might help. Did you try clustering your data into groups and then finding the average CPM value of all groups to decide which one might be the best?